# Boxing in Java

Tags: java

Добрый день. Читаю , про автоупаковку в Java и появился вопрос :

```
    Integer i0 = 100;
    Integer i1 = new Integer(100);
    System.out.println(i0 == i1);
```

Почему результат false ? Ведь , если сделать так :

```
    Integer i0 = 100;
    Integer i1 = 100;
    System.out.println(i0 == i1);
```

То результат будет true. Хотя в первом примере строка :

```
    Integer i1 = new Integer(100);
```

Где значение 100 тоже упаковывается, но только вручную, а не автоматически (как во втором примере) в объект типа Integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Такой код

```
Integer i0 = 100;
```

эквивалентент такому:

```
Integer i0 = Integer.valueOf(100);
```

Если взглянуть на реализацию метода `valueOf`, то можно увидеть, что для значений от -128 до 127 используется кэш объектов типа `Integer`. См. так же документацию метода `valueOf`.

При вызове же конструктора кэш не используется и создается новый экземпляр класса `Integer`.

Comment: Скажите, но строчка System.out.println(i0 == i1) ведь проверяет не равенство i0 и i1, а проверяет указывают ли ссылки этих объектов на одну и туже область памяти. Тогда как во втором примере результат может быть true ?

Comment: @Drylozav: потому что в этом случае вызывается 2 раза `valueOf`, которое возвращает один и тот же — закешированный ведь! — объект.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю вообще , что значит "вернуть закешированный объект" ? Что происходит с объектом, когда его заносят в кеш ?

Comment: @Drylozav Ничего с ним не происходит :) Просто используется один и тот же объект чтобы не выделять для него память, а потом и не освобождать. Оптимизация такая. См. определение http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88

Comment: @Drylozav: если по-простому: функция `valueOf`, когда её первый раз вызвали с аргументом 100, создаёт новый объект, и запоминает его в нычку. Когда её во второй раз вызовут с аргументом 100, она вспомнит, что объект у неё уже заныкан, новый создавать не будет, а отдаст старый во второй раз. (В торговле такие трюки наказываются тюрьмой, а в программировании, видите, прокатывает.)

Comment: Спасибо , очень доступно объяснили. Скажите, а в данном случае в Java под кешем не подразумевается stack или heap, которые как раз выступают подобными "нычками" ?

Comment: @Drylozav Для хранения используется обычный массив. Стэк и куча используются для другого. Ну посмотрите же уже на исходники класса java.lang.Integer :)

Comment: Я смотрел. Мне как раз не понятно собственно зачем вообще такая идея. Какова цель хранить объекты в кеше ?

Comment: @Drylozav: Потому что создание объекта — немного более медленная операция, чем выборка готового из массива. Поскольку неявное боксирование маленьких чисел является в Java очень-очень-очень частой операцией, такая оптимизация оправдана.

Answer (score 5):

Ну первый пример почему `false` это понятно, поскольку сравниваются ссылки на разные объекты.

Во втором случае, по идее должно было бы быть тоже `false`, но проблема в том, что автобоксируемые объекты кэшируются и при втором вызове `i1=100` будет возвращен ранее созданный при `i0=100` объект, поэтому сравнение и возвращает `true`

В общем такие вещи делать с автобоксингом не рекомендуется. Автобоксинг был придуман не для этого.

Comment: а для чего ? собственно я так и не понял зачем вообще придумана идея кеширования объектов ? И почему именно в диапазоне -128...127 ? Это какой то "костыль" разработчиков ?

Comment: @Drylozav Этот диапазон можно настроить на свое усмотрение (но не меньше чем дефолтный). Это не костыль, это оптимизация. В первую очередь оптимизируется расход памяти, и, как следствие, производительность. Предполагается, что малые целые числа очень часто используются разработчиками по сравнению с большими, и потому их решили закэшировать.

Comment: @Drylozav
Это кэширование - определенного рода оптимизация, чтобы сэкономить в таких случаях как циклы for. -128...127 - это диапазон байта. 

@a_gura, эт Вы где видели такую настройку?;-)

Comment: @JEcho Цитирую доки из сырца
`/**
     * Cache to support the object identity semantics of autoboxing for values between
     * -128 and 127 (inclusive) as required by JLS.
     *
     * The cache is initialized on first usage.  The size of the cache
     * may be controlled by the -XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<size> option.
     * During VM initialization, java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high property
     * may be set and saved in the private system properties in the
     * sun.misc.VM class.
     */`