# Классы обертки в Java

Tags: классы, java

Добрый день. Буквально вчера задавал вопрос ([Boxing in Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/264637/boxing-in-java)) и так с ним не разобрался до конца.

Например, если у меня есть код:

```
    Integer x = 500;
    Integer y = 200;
    Integer z = x + y;
```

Как будет вычисляться это выражение ? (Я имею в виду, сколько операция `boxing/unboxing` произойдет, что бы вычислялось это выражение ?)
Искал в спецификации про boxing/unboxing, но нашел только ([Autoboxing and Unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html))

Comment: Вы не спецификацию смотрите, а учебник. Спецификация здесь: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html См. раздел 5. Conversions and Promotions.

Comment: Я там тоже смотрел. Но там написано, что для boxing/unboxing используется только один метод intValue. Про ValueOf слова.

Comment: @Drylozav Я не знаю, как вы смотрели, но там этого не сказано.

Comment: Я это и имел в виду. Про операцию ValueOf не сказано. Поэтому я и не понял почему  Integer x = 1000 эквивалентно Integer.valueOf(1000)

Comment: @Drylozav Можете поверить на слово или посмотреть на получившийся байткод.

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer x = 1000; // Integer.valueOf() - boxing 1
Integer y = 2000; // Integer.valueOf() - boxing 2
Integer z = x + y; // Integer.intValue() + Integer.intValue - (unboxing 1 + unboxing 2) и присваивание boxing 3
```

Итого: boxing - 3 раза, unboxing - 2 раза.

Comment: Скажите, а в чем отличие между Integer x = 1000 и Integer.valueOf(1000) ? Или это просто взаимно заменяемые способы ?

Comment: @Drylozav Boxing/unboxing - это просто синтаксический сахар, упрощающий жизнь программистам. Начиная с Java 5 выражение `Integer x = 1000` трактуется компилятором как выражение `Integer x = Integer.valueOf(1000)`. На выходе получится одинаковый байткод, так что разницы никакой. До Java 5 выражение `Integer x = 1000` просто бы не откомпилировалось.